# How do you index and use current and previous column values to calculate the next column value in a pandas.apply function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to build a function that calculates trailing stop values using Close and ATR values from a pandas dataframe.

The dataframe for reference is as follows:

```
            High    Low     Open    Close       ATR 
Date                                
2020-06-01  5.88    5.67    5.73    5.87        0.210000    
2020-06-02  6.00    5.83    5.96    5.90        0.207143    
2020-06-03  6.27    5.92    5.99    6.19        0.218776    
2020-06-04  6.58    6.12    6.20    6.57        0.236006    
2020-06-05  7.50    7.02    7.24    7.34        0.285577    
2020-06-08  7.74    7.37    7.53    7.53        0.293750    
2020-06-09  7.44    7.05    7.22    7.24        0.307053    
2020-06-10  7.34    6.77    7.33    6.81        0.325835    
2020-06-11  6.46    6.04    6.07    6.13        0.357561
```

What I want it to look like:

```
            High    Low     Open    Close       ATR         ATR_TS
Date                                
2020-06-01  5.88    5.67    5.73    5.87        0.210000    5.135000
2020-06-02  6.00    5.83    5.96    5.90        0.207143    5.175000
2020-06-03  6.27    5.92    5.99    6.19        0.218776    5.424286
2020-06-04  6.58    6.12    6.20    6.57        0.236006    5.743980
2020-06-05  7.50    7.02    7.24    7.34        0.285577    6.340481
2020-06-08  7.74    7.37    7.53    7.53        0.293750    6.501876
2020-06-09  7.44    7.05    7.22    7.24        0.307053    6.501876
2020-06-10  7.34    6.77    7.33    6.81        0.325835    6.501876
2020-06-11  6.46    6.04    6.07    6.13        0.357561    7.381464
```

My pseudo-function/logic at the moment looks like this:

```
def atr_ts(close, atr):
    bigatr = atr*3.5
    buysell = 1 
    stop[i-1] = 0  
    
    if buysell > 0:
        stop = close - bigatr
        stop = max(stop, stop[i-1])
        if close < stop:
            stop = close + bigatr
            buysell = -1

    elif buysell < 0:
        stop = close + bigatr
        stop = min(stop, stop[i-1])
        if close > stop:
            stop = close - bigatr
            buysell = 1
        
            
    return stop

df['ATR_TS'] = df.apply(lambda col: atr_ts(col['Close'], col['ATR']), axis = 1)
```

So my question is, how do I index the previous stop (ATR_TS) values that are calculated by this function in order to calculate the next stop value, with the first stop value being 0?
If anyone sees a better solution to this problem without using pandas.apply, do also share.

I'm new to programming in general so my apologies if clarity is lacking.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In `pandas` you can use shift() to refer to the row before the one you're in (or shift(n) for the nth)

Comment: I really do not see how you are calculating atr_ts? How do you get the values in the first three rows for example?

Comment: @DjerroNeth so for all the rows up until and including the first occurrence of 6.501876, it's just `stop = close - bigatr`. The second occurrence of 6.501876 is the result of what would be `max(stop, stop[i-1])` because the next `close - bigatr` is smaller. So therefore the next if statement is satisfied. I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be the final solution, as I am confused as to why the last value of `ATR_TS` = `7.381464`, although I know how you calculated the value. I created a number of columns to visualize the "pandonic" way of doing some of the calculations using `.shift()` and `.cumsum()` for row-wise comparisons. Please take a look at the columns and my screenshot and explain how to get the last value, but in the final solution there is absolutely no need for all of these columns:

```
df['bigatr'] = (df['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop1a'] = df['Close'] - (df['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop2a'] = df.shift()['Close'] - (df.shift()['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop3a'] = df[['Stop1a','Stop2a']].max(axis=1)
df['Stop1b'] = df['Close'] + (df['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop2b'] = df.shift()['Close'] + (df.shift()['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop3b'] = df[['Stop1b','Stop2b']].min(axis=1)
df['cuma'] = (df['Stop1a'] > df.shift()['Stop1a']).cumsum()
df['cumb'] = (df['Stop1b'] < df.shift()['Stop1b']).cumsum()
df['ATR_TSa'] = df.groupby((df['Stop1a'] > df.shift()['Stop1a']).cumsum())['Stop1a'].transform('first')
df['ATR_TSb'] = df.groupby((df['Stop1b'] < df.shift()['Stop1b']).cumsum())['Stop1b'].transform('first')
df
```

[image]

As you can see, the final solution is all of the `['ATR_TSa']` values circled in `red` and the `df['ATR_TSb']` value circled in `blue` in the last row.

---

EDIT #1 - Per OP's comment, the final logic to solve the above is to add:

```
 df['ATR_TS'] = np.where((df['Close'] < df['ATR_TSa']), df['ATR_TSb'], df['ATR_TSa'])
```

Now, below here, I will provide a more concise solution:

```
df['Stop1a'] = df['Close'] - (df['ATR'] * 3.5)
df['Stop1b'] = df['Close'] + (df['ATR'] * 3.5)
a = df.groupby((df['Stop1a'] > df.shift()['Stop1a']).cumsum())['Stop1a'].transform('first')
b = df.groupby((df['Stop1b'] <= df.shift()['Stop1b']).cumsum())['Stop1b'].transform('first')
df['ATR_TS'] = np.where((df['Close'] < a), b, a)
df = df.drop(['Stop1a','Stop1b'], axis=1)
df


Out[1]: 
         Date  High   Low  Open  Close       ATR    ATR_TS
0  2020-06-01  5.88  5.67  5.73   5.87  0.210000  5.135000
1  2020-06-02  6.00  5.83  5.96   5.90  0.207143  5.175000
2  2020-06-03  6.27  5.92  5.99   6.19  0.218776  5.424284
3  2020-06-04  6.58  6.12  6.20   6.57  0.236006  5.743979
4  2020-06-05  7.50  7.02  7.24   7.34  0.285577  6.340480
5  2020-06-08  7.74  7.37  7.53   7.53  0.293750  6.501875
6  2020-06-09  7.44  7.05  7.22   7.24  0.307053  6.501875
7  2020-06-10  7.34  6.77  7.33   6.81  0.325835  6.501875
8  2020-06-11  6.46  6.04  6.07   6.13  0.357561  7.381463
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I see how you got those values and am happy to clarify the last value.  Referencing your code, the `['ATR_TSa']` value `(6.501875)` in that row is what you derive from the first `if` statement, but the `['Close']` value in that row `(6.13)` is the first time `['Close'] < ['ATR_TSa']` so therefore the `['ATR_TSb']` value satisfies, `buysell = -1` and from then on, the `elif` statement runs until `['Close'] > ['ATR_TSb']`.
My goal is to have this function so that I can use it with any historical trading data. I hope that clarifies. Thanks again!

Comment: @jantarktic adding this one line of code would solve then, I think? `df['ATR_TS'] = np.where((df['Close'] < df['ATR_TSa']), df['ATR_TSb'], df['ATR_TSa'])` I will also create a more concise solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and I appreciate the insight into your workflow. Keeping the code in "pandonic" helps a lot in the long run.